# How can I get a Twitter screenname/username with the twitter_oauth gem using their id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

How can I get a Twitter screenname/username with the [twitter_oauth](https://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth) gem using their id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, a sample in irb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter_oauth'
client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new
id = '5452272'  
temp = client.show(id)
puts "Screenname: #{temp['screen_name']}, UserName: #{temp['name']}"
```